# MSVS 2015 building a dll - unresolved external symbol _main in invoke_main in MSVCRTD.lib (exe_main.obj)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, program-entry-point

I want to compile a DLL and use it in my project. (It has to be a DLL because I am using Windows Hooks and it has to be loaded at runtime). For more information, it uses Allegro 5 from Nuget.

I am getting the following error when I try to build my DLL:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) in file MSVCRTD.lib (exe_main.obj)
```

I've recreated the project several times now due to configuration issues. My latest iteration is Win32 Windowed Application and DLL being built with the Multi Threaded Debug DLL runtime - I have tried all the other options and none of the rest work.

I don't understand why it's searching for main: it's a DLL. I haven't provided a DLLMain as I understood it's not necessary because MSVS will provide it for you.

How would I resolve this build issue when trying to compile my DLL?

EDIT
The solution was to #define ALLEGRO_NO_MAGIC_MAIN. The Allegro library expects a main function unless you define ALLEGRO_NO_MAGIC_MAIN. Problem solved.

Comment: It's probably looking for a main because something is wrong in the configuration. Main is needed for an exe and there is something in the build that makes it want to build an exe, albeit you want to build a dll. If you are using Visual Studio, use the wizard to lay down a dll project and then compare the settings with yours.

Comment: I already used it to create a DLL project. It doesn't work. I don't know what you want me to do. I created a new project, selected Win32 application, hit next, selected DLL project and then said ok. It doesn't build.

Comment: The settings use the Windows subsystem, and the configuration type is DLL. It still asks for _main.

Comment: I appreciate your frustration, these linker errors can be a real pain to solve. Does the build fail even with an empty project as generated by the wizard? is `_DLL` defined in the project? If an empty wizard generated project fails, your installation may be broken somehow...

Comment: I found the solution. Allegro expects a main function. I needed to define ALLEGRO_NO_MAGIC_MAIN. I figured it out after trying a test dll project. That worked without problems so I knew it was my code causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to #define ALLEGRO_NO_MAGIC_MAIN before including Allegro 5 headers. Allegro expects to see a main function, and that is why the linker was looking for it.